# read files pdf on browser

Tags: php

alguém poderia me ajudar com um problema, como posso obter um link de um arquivo pdf e abri-lo no próprio navegador usando php
nota: a varialvel $arquivo = 'artigo.pdf' vem do banco de dados.

```
 <ul class="list-group mt-4">
                <?php
                    foreach ($this->Dados['sts_artigos_cientificos'] as $cientificos) {
                        extract($cientificos);
                    ?>
                        <li class="bg-secondary list-group-item d-flex 
                        justify-content-between align-items-center ">
                            <a class="text-white" href="<?php echo URL . '/assets/files/pdf/'
                            . $id . '/' . $arquivo; ?>" target="blank"><?php echo $titulo; ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Faça isso simplesmente mandando um arquivo como resposta a qualquer URL. Isso normalmente basta. Há um simples visualizador de pdf em qualquer navegador moderno.

Comment: pessoal obrigado acabei resolvendo mudando a query onde eu trago as informações do banco de dados "$Listar->fullRead('SELECT id, titulo, arquivo FROM sts_artigos_cientificos ORDER BY id DESC', 'LIMIT :limit','limit=10');"